# Powershell with Sharepoint module - contradictory Error-Messages

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to run the command "Get-SPWeb" from the SharePoint-Snapin for Powershell.

If I start PS normal (.net Ver.4), this is the error:

```
"Get-SPWeb: Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with Version 4.0.3.... of the Microsoft .Net Runtime."
```

Alright, so simply put `-Version 2` behind the PS-Shortcut so it starts with Version 2? See what happens:

```
Error: Import-Module: [...] The Module 'SharePoint' requires a minimum version of '4.0' to execute
```

If I wouldn´t be mad as hell, I would just laugh about it.

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

This is the code by the way (important parts):

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://myaddress.com/myreport"
```

Edit: Version-Info´s:

The Version-check provides the following:

```
PSVersion:  2.0
CLRVersion: 2.0. ....
Build: 6.1. ...
```

And with the normal PS:

```
PSVersion: 3.0
CLRVersion: 4.0
Build: 6.2
```

Also, I always start with the x64-version as administrator

Edit2: This is how the errors look:

[image: Trying to run with ver. 2]

[image: Trying to run with normal ver.]

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? SharePoint 2010 indeed only supports .net framework 3.5.

Comment: I use SharePoint 2010 - so how can I force Powershell to use .net 3.5 ? And why does it say "requires Minimum 4.0" ?

Comment: Well, providing -Version 2 you actually specify version of powershell and not .net.  See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344855/which-net-version-is-my-powershell-script-using. Try to check which version of .net you using. Also you need to use x64 version of powershell because SharePoint object model does not support x86.

Comment: That is really odd that it says that it need version 4.0. I have on my SharePoint powershell 2.0 and it works perfectly. Have you tried specifying Version 2.0 instead of just 2?

Comment: The Version-check provides the following:
PSVersion:  2.0
CLRVersion: 2.0. ....
Build: 6.1. ...


And with the normal PS:
PSVersion: 3.0
CLRVersion: 4.0
Build: 6.2

Also, I always start with the x64-version as administrator

Comment: Can you please add it to your post? BTW i do not see version information in your comment :).

Comment: Sorry, I thought enter was "shift-enter" :)

Comment: Wait, are you using SharePoint online? Why it says Microsoft.Online.SharePoint ?

Comment: I tried both, SP online Shell and the "normal" shell