# OleDb data provider give error E_NOINTERFACE

Tags: c#, powershell, oledb

**c# code that doesn't work:**

```
string connectionString = "Provider=OvHOleDbProv.OvHOleDbProv.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password;Data Source=192.168.7.96;Location=\"\";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"\";";
OleDbConnection _connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
_connection.Open();
DataTable schema = _connection.GetSchema("Tables"); // Exception see below
_connection.Close();
```

**Exception:**

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004002): Сбой
>   "OvHOleDbProv.OvHOleDbProv.1" без сообщения об ошибке, код результата:
>   E_NOINTERFACE(0x80004002).
>
> в
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult
>   hr)
>
> в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.GetSchemaRowset(Guid
>   schema, Object[] restrictions)
>
> в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(Guid schema,
>   Object[] restrictions)
>
> в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbMetaDataFactory.PrepareCollection(String
>   collectionName, String[] restrictions, DbConnection connection)
>
> в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbMetaDataFactory.GetSchema(DbConnection
>   connection, String collectionName, String[] restrictions)
>
> в
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.GetSchema(DbConnectionFactory
>   factory, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnection
>   outerConnection, String collectionName, String[] restrictions)
>
> в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.GetSchema(String collectionName,
>   String[] restrictionValues)
>
> в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.GetSchema(String collectionName)
>
> в SourceModule.Ovation.ApiOvation.ExportSignals(String filename) в
>   E:\tfs\vm-tfs\SAn\Source
>   code\SourceModules\Ovation\Development\Version
>   2\SourceModule.Ovation\ApiOvation.cs:строка 58
>
> в SourceModule.Ovation.Program.Main(String[] args) в
>   E:\tfs\vm-tfs\SAn\Source
>   code\SourceModules\Ovation\Development\Version
>   2\SourceModule.Ovation\Program.cs:строка 20

**c# code that works:**

```
string connectionString = "Provider=OvHOleDbProv.OvHOleDbProv.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password;Data Source=192.168.7.96;Location=\"\";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"\";";
OleDbConnection _connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
_connection.Open();
DataTable schema = _connection.GetSchema("Restrictions");
_connection.Close();
```

**PS code that works for both cases:**

```
$connectionString='Provider=OvHOleDbProv.OvHOleDbProv.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password;Data Source=192.168.7.96;Location="";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties="";' 
$oCon = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $connectionString 
$oCon.Open() 
$schema = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$schema = $oCon.GetSchema("Tables") 
$schema
$schema = $oCon.GetSchema("Restrictions")
$schema
$oCon.Close()
```

**Restrictions output include collectionName "Tables":**

> CollectionName RestrictionName RestrictionDefault RestrictionNumber
>   -------------- --------------- ------------------ -----------------
>   Columns        TABLE_CATALOG                                      1
>   Columns        TABLE_SCHEMA                                       2
>   Columns        TABLE_NAME                                         3
>   Columns        COLUMN_NAME                                        4
>   Tables         TABLE_CATALOG                                      1
>   Tables         TABLE_SCHEMA                                       2
>   Tables         TABLE_NAME                                         3
>   Tables         TABLE_TYPE                                         4

Comment: what's in Tables? what's in Restrictions?

Comment: @FrancescoB. , [msdn_restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/schema-restrictions). In **Tables** list of available tables in Database.

Comment: Yep, I saw the same page. What I don't understand is: why not use the same syntax? I.e.
`string[] restrictions = new string[4];  
        restrictions[1] = "Sales";  
        System.Data.DataTable table = connection.GetSchema(  
          "Tables", restrictions);`

Comment: @FrancescoB., I can add link to files with result of GetSchema("Tables") and GetSchema("Restrictions") in PS.

Comment: @FrancescoB., I tried to use this syntax, but it also leads to an error. I can repeat it, but you need to wait a bit. The version of the oledb driver is old, and perhaps not complete. Because of this, there are many problems.

Comment: @FrancescoB., Oh, wait. Because I do not need restrictions. But in the PS works well. In c# received the same error.

Comment: @FrancescoB., I think that the error is due to the version of .NET framework. But how to determine which of the installed versions of the framework uses PS now? And I do not have any documentation for this oledb driver.

Comment: @FrancescoB., I can connect to the database from the Excel using this driver. And he also successfully gets a list of tables in the database.

Comment: apparently you can see what version of .NET PS is using like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3347907/5480409)

Comment: @FrancescoB., thank you. CLRVersion 4.0.30319. I'll try to build my application for this version.

Comment: @FrancescoB., No, it did not help.

Comment: what's the framework version your project is compiled for? by the way, is .NET 2.0 installed on your system?

Comment: @FrancescoB., using [clrver](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/tools/clrver-exe-clr-version-tool): v.1.1.4322, v.2.0.50727, v.4.0.30319. App.config: <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0.3"/>. In project properties: .NET Framework 4.

Comment: are you compiling to 32 or 64 bit? can you try both ways?

Comment: @FrancescoB., Ovh Provider supports only 32 bit.

Comment: How is OvHOleDbProv defined?

Comment: @FrancescoB., Sorry, I did not understand the question. OvHOleDbProv.OvHOleDbProv.1 is name of oledb provider. I installed it. It works to some extent. With its help, I get the necessary data from the database. But for a new task, I'd like to get a scheme (because getting works in PS :) ).

Comment: Just not to give up on anything, what happens if you surround Restrictions in brackets, i.e. `[Restrictions]`?

Comment: @FrancescoB., `System.Data.DataTable schema = _connection.GetSchema("[Restrictions]");` result exception: ex.Message = "the requested collection ([Restrictions]) is not defined.", ex.InnerException = null, ex.StackTrace = "in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbMetaDataFactory.FindMetaDataCollectionRow(String collectionName)\r\n in ....".

Comment: I found a [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1378795.aspx?How+can+I+get+table+relationship+from+connection+GetSchema+) suggesting to try `GetOleDbSchemaTable` instead of `GetSchema`, with or without brackets

Comment: @FrancescoB., I know about this method. The same result. In PS work well, c# - error.
I can give access to tfs for convenience. So you can write tests, task. I'll check them. For this I need your email. Of course, if it's convenient for you

Comment: @FrancescoB., thank you very much for trying to find a solution. I found another way to solve.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code returns a list of tables in the database and save to xml:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=OvHOleDbProv.OvHOleDbProv.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password;Data Source=192.168.7.96;Location=\"\";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"\";";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand() { Connection = connection, CommandText = "select TABLE_NAME from SYSTABLES where TABLE_TYPE='TABLE'" };
OleDbDataReader datareader = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable data = new DataTable();
data.Load(datareader);
data.TableName = "SYSTABLES"; // necessary for writing to xml
data.WriteXml("tables.xml");
connection.Close();
```