# C# and CLR versions

Tags: c#, clr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the .NET Framework, CLR and Visual Studio version numbers relate to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212896/how-do-the-net-framework-clr-and-visual-studio-version-numbers-relate-to-each-o)

Recently I was searching for a documentation on CLR, C# version mapping right from 1.0 to 4.0, but didn't find any good resources. It would be very helpful, If anyone could provide me this information or link to any resources.

Comment: Don't know exactly what you're after, but wikipedia has some good info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework and here as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions

Comment: What kind of documentation? There is enough on msdn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The release schedule was as follows:-

C# 1 + CLR 1

C# 2 + CLR 2

C# 3 + **CLR 2**

C# 4 + CLR 4