# Should GetMember return an abstract property on a closed type?

Tags: c#, reflection, clr

I'm seeing two different behaviors based on the CLR that my application is being run under. In one case it returns an abstract property on a closed type and in another it does not. As the property is abstract, it feels more like the first is correct.

I have tested by compiling the following under VS2010 targeting .NET-3.5 SP1 and then copying the physical executable to another machine with a different CLR minor revision:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<TId>
{
    public abstract TId PK { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedEntity : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public override int PK { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var derivedEntity = new DerivedEntity();
        var type = derivedEntity.GetType();
        var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty;
        foreach (var memberInfo in type.GetMember("PK", flags))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Member: " + memberInfo.Name
                + " from " + memberInfo.DeclaringType);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Running : " + Environment.Version);
        Console.WriteLine("mscorlib:   " + typeof(int).Assembly.GetName().Version);
    }
}
```

On the machine running 2.0.50727.4952 I see the following output:

```
Member: PK from MemberInfoTest.DerivedEntity
Running : 2.0.50727.4952
mscorlib:   2.0.0.0
```

On a machine running 2.0.50727.3615 I get different output:

```
Member: PK from MemberInfoTest.DerivedEntity
Member: PK from MemberInfoTest.BaseEntity`1[System.Int32]
Running : 2.0.50727.3615
mscorlib:   2.0.0.0
```

The above differences cause an `AmbiguousMatchException` under various circumstances. Which of these behaviors is correct and is there a "fix" for the other?

**EDIT:** I just tested targeting the CLR-4 runtime and the abstract closed property is not returned in either case, further suggesting in my mind that the first behavior is correct.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but this link might help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212896/how-do-the-net-framework-clr-and-visual-studio-version-numbers-relate-to-each-o

Comment: You're really talking about an abstract *property* (`PK`), not about a *method*, aren't you?

Comment: @stakx You're right, corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why this behavior occurs.  My guess is you are seeing an RTM and SP1 CLR and reflection has a subtle difference / bug between the 2 versions.

You can fix this problem by stating you want the `PK` member which is declared on the specific type you are doing `GetMembers` on by setting `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`.  The `DeclaredOnly` will limit the return members to only those members which are declared on the specific type.  It will filter out any members declared on parent types.

Comment: +1 for seeing through the question to the root cause. `DeclaredOnly` won't always work for us because of our true inheritance hierarchy. I'm hoping to figure out the correct behavior so I know whether to patch our application or, if possible, have the offending machines updated.