# Do I have SP1 installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Does the indicate that I am on the latest Service Pack, which I assume is SP1, found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)?

I am confused by the "SP" with no number following "Version 9.0"

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version
>   9.0.30729.1 SP Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1
>
> Installed Edition: Enterprise
>
> Microsoft Visual Basic 2008
>   91904-270-9442995-60975 Microsoft
>   Visual Basic 2008
>
> Microsoft Visual C# 2008
>   91904-270-9442995-60975 Microsoft
>   Visual C# 2008
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team
>   Explorer   91904-270-9442995-60975
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team
>   Explorer Version 9.0.30729.1
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for
>   Office   91904-270-9442995-60975
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for
>   Office
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Team System
>   2008 Development Edition
>   91904-270-9442995-60975 Microsoft
>   Visual Studio Team System 2008
>   Development Edition
>
> Portions of International
>   CorrectSpell™ spelling correction
>   system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie
>   Speech Products N.V.  All rights
>   reserved.
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of
>   the English Language, Third Edition
>   Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin
>   Company.  Electronic version licensed
>   from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products
>   N.V.  All rights reserved.
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for
>   Applications 2.0
>   91904-270-9442995-60975 Microsoft
>   Visual Studio Tools for Applications
>   2.0
>
> Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008
>   91904-270-9442995-60975 Microsoft
>   Visual Web Developer 2008
>
> CodeRush for Visual Studio   10.2
>
> DXCore for Visual Studio   10.2 DXCore
>   for Visual Studio
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2008 Team Explorer - ENU (KB946260)
>   KB946260 This hotfix is for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer -
>   ENU. If you later install a more
>   recent service pack, this hotfix will
>   be uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946260.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2008 Team Explorer - ENU (KB946458)
>   KB946458 This hotfix is for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer -
>   ENU. If you later install a more
>   recent service pack, this hotfix will
>   be uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946458.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2008 Team Explorer - ENU (KB947171)
>   KB947171 This hotfix is for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer -
>   ENU. If you later install a more
>   recent service pack, this hotfix will
>   be uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947171.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2008 Team Explorer - ENU (KB947180)
>   KB947180 This hotfix is for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer -
>   ENU. If you later install a more
>   recent service pack, this hotfix will
>   be uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947180.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2008 Team Explorer - ENU (KB948816)
>   KB948816 This hotfix is for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer -
>   ENU. If you later install a more
>   recent service pack, this hotfix will
>   be uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948816.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB944899)   KB944899 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944899.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB945282)   KB945282 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945282.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB946040)   KB946040 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946040.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB946308)   KB946308 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946308.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB946344)   KB946344 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946344.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB946581)   KB946581 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946581.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB947173)   KB947173 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947173.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB947540)   KB947540 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947540.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB947789)   KB947789 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947789.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB948127)   KB948127 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948127.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB953256)   KB953256 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953256.
>
> Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB971092)   KB971092 This hotfix
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this hotfix will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971092.
>
> Microsoft Recipe Framework Package
>   8.0 This package provides services to the guidance packages.
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team
>   Explorer - ENU Service Pack 1
>   (KB945140)   KB945140 This service
>   pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2008 Team Explorer - ENU. If you later
>   install a more recent service pack,
>   this service pack will be uninstalled
>   automatically. For more information,
>   visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945140.
>
> PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2008
>   1.0 A set of power commands for Visual Studio 2008
>
> Refactor! for Visual Studio   10.2
>   Refactor! for Visual Studio
>
> Security Update for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio Team System 2008 Development
>   Edition - ENU (KB972222)   KB972222
>   This security update is for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio Team System 2008
>   Development Edition - ENU. If you
>   later install a more recent service
>   pack, this security update will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972222.
>
> Security Update for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio Team System 2008 Development
>   Edition - ENU (KB973675)   KB973675
>   This security update is for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio Team System 2008
>   Development Edition - ENU. If you
>   later install a more recent service
>   pack, this security update will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973675.
>
> SourceOutliner   1.0 Creates a tool
>   window that provides an outline view
>   of a source code file.
>
> Update for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB956453)   KB956453 This update
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this update will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956453.
>
> Update for Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Team System 2008 Development Edition -
>   ENU (KB967143)   KB967143 This update
>   is for Microsoft Visual Studio Team
>   System 2008 Development Edition - ENU.
>   If you later install a more recent
>   service pack, this update will be
>   uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967143.
>
> CodeLibSQLVS For more information
>   about fish's dotNET, see the fish's
>   dotNET website at
>   http://fishcodelib.com/ Copyright (c)
>   2005-2009 fish.
>
> Search Work Items SearchWorkItems is
>   provided by Noah Coad, for more
>   information, see:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/noahc/archive/2007/03/08/search-work-items-team-system-addin.aspx

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212896/how-do-the-net-framework-clr-and-visual-studio-version-numbers-relate-to-each-o/212929#212929 for a complete list of version numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have SP1 and I have

> Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM

So it looks like yes, you have SP1

Answer (score 1):

That's what it says in the About box of my copy of VS2008, just plain "9.0.30729.1 SP".  I know for a fact that I have the service pack installed.  And there is only one, there is never going to be another.  Clearly you have it too.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says - .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1

Comment: I don't think the OP is not asking about .NET but Visual Studio, especially given the tag.

Comment: Sorry - I meant "I don't think the OP is asking..." ;)

Answer (score 0):

left field answer ....

PSI from http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/ will tell you if you don't have all Service packs and hotfixes etc for VisualStudio and many other programs.

Comment: Not sure why this got spam flagged, neither the answer nor user look very suspicious to me.

Comment: LOL.  I find heuristic based Spam and AV filters frequently think I'm evil :-)