# Can more than one CLR version be present in a single machine?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

i faced this question in an interview, 
        Is it possible to have more than one version of CLR in a single machine?
    pls provide me the details if u know - i mean if its not possible why? otherwise by default which one will be used?. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can install 1.0, 1.1, 2.0 (up to 3.5) and 4.0 in the same machine...

But you can only host one version in each process (not sure if this changed with 4.0)..

Edit:
A assembly is compiled against a specific CLR version and that CLR version will be used..

Comment: the CLR that ends up hosting it can be slightly different, IIRC

Comment: Yes. As far as I know, an assembly compiled against *.NET framework* version 2.0 will use *.NET framework* version 2.0 SP1 instead if it is installed.

Comment: BTW: There is not CLR version 3.0 or 3.5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212896/how-do-the-net-framework-clr-and-visual-studio-version-numbers-relate-to-each-o

Comment: It is **important** to note that .NET Framework 4.0 is not like the others. It can be used in the same process together with other frameworks. To test, create a new .NET 4.0 project and reference an older CLR version project. No errors, no warnings.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN

> Starting with the .NET Framework
>   version 4, you can use in-process
>   side-by-side hosting to run multiple
>   versions of the common language
>   runtime (CLR) in a single process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876.aspx