# How to learn the exact version of the .NET platform?

Tags: c#, .net

The code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);
```

returns identical results (2.0.50727.5448) for [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Framework 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 SP1. How do I  learn the exact version of the installed .NET platform?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565434/howto-find-net-version

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-net-framework-verison-using-c

Comment: Yes, all those versions of the framework use the same runtime version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read registry keys to detect versions at service pack granularity. [This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318785/how-to-determine-which-versions-and-service-pack-levels-of-the-microso) explains what key/value pairs you need to look for.

For example, you can tell `3.5` from `3.5 SP1` by looking at values inside

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5
```

"plain" 3.5 has `Install = 1`, while `SP1` has `SP >=1`.

Scroll to the bottom of the article at the link to see the entire table.

Comment: I need to specify only the current platform, instead of all what are available on the computer

Comment: How the register can help to learn to me information on that platform on which the code is now executed?

Comment: @EvgenyGorb Done. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 4):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion()
```

Comment: no, it is the wrong response. In this case I receive it (for all): v2.0.50727

Comment: @Bush: are you sure your code doesn't actually run on 2.0.50727? You can check this by examining the loaded dlls at runtime.

Comment: @Vlad: In the MS Visual Studio project I change a target platform for 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 SP1 and I receive the same value for both specified above code options.

Answer (score 4):

2.0, 3,0, 3,5 and 3.5SPx all based on the same set of core 2.0 libraries. Essentially all of these versions are 2.0 plus additional components. This answer contains the list of versions: [How do the .NET Framework, CLR and Visual Studio version numbers relate to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212896/how-do-the-net-framework-clr-and-visual-studio-version-numbers-relate-to-each) and related information.

So when you ask what run-time environment version is you'll get 2.0 (the other variants are 1, 1.1 and 4.0 as far as I know).

If you need 3/3.5/SP distinction @dasblinkenlight gave you an answer. Otherwise explain what you trying to do to get more suggestions.